# SQL trouble with JOIN on INSTR()

Tags: sql, left-join, conditional-statements

I've read lots of examples of JOIN syntax, but none of them work for my problem.

I have a table of **quotes** and a table of sales **enquiries**.  One quote may result in multiple enquiries, or it may not result in any enquiries.  I want to create a list of all quotes and include details of any resulting enquiry.  I'm expecting multiple result rows for a quote that resulted in many enquiries.  I'm expecting a single row with empty or null enquiries fields, for those quotes that didn't give rise to any enquiries.

The connecting data is in the quotes table, where there's a field called 'activity' that contains the id of any or all enquiries that resulted.  It's updated each tim e anew enquiry comes in.

So I tried this:

```
SELECT q.*, e.id, e.price
FROM quotes as q
LEFT JOIN enquiries as e
ON INSTR(q.activity, e.id) >'0'
WHERE q.date > '2013-07-01'
```

But every row in my results includes enquiries data.  I can't seem to get it to include the quotes that never resulted in anything.  I thought LEFT JOIN was supposed to give me all of the quotes regardless of enquiries, and include the enquiries data where there was a match.  But every example I've seen is just joining on a.id = b.id, so I suspect that my INSTR() match criteria might be messing things up.

Comment: Your query looks like it should return all rows in quotes.  Check the complete set of returned results, these might be at the end.  Also, you can remove the single quotes around `'0'`.  And, what database are you using?

Comment: If you're storing multiple foreign key values in one column, which it sounds like you are, you really should think a bit about normalizing your data model. Multi-valued attributes are a recipe for future headache in a relational model.

Comment: I agree that having multiple keys in one column isn't ideal.  I'd say present headaches, not future headaches!  But that's what I am stuck with for now.  Gordon, what did you mean by "..return all rows in quotes"? I'm definitely not getting rows where e.id is not in a q.activity field.  I only get rows where the INSTR condition is true.  HELP! Somebody help!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And as Gordon also said: don't use string literals to compare numbers. `'0'` is a string, `0` is a number

Comment: The join clause is fine and correct. All your quotes contain a relation to an enquiry.

Answer (score 0):

As previous commentators have suggested the issue will be down to the join with Instr. The return value from INSTR of many RDBMSs is an integer value. When you therefore test the value of INSTR against '0' you won't get a match. Also, if Instr doesn't find a match you may get something else returned like MS Access where Null is a possible return value. This is obviously all speculation and we really need to see an example of your data and the issue to confirm if this is the actual problem. In the absence of any more info this is the best you are going to get:

Without knowing which DB you are using I've included a few links for INSTR:

[MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr),

[Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm),

[MS Access (returns variant Long)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/instr-function-HA001228857.aspx),

[SQL Server - No Instr Function - CharIndex](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be somewhere else, because this seems to work fine for me. I assumed the list of enquiries was just a comma separated string. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71ce1/1

Get rid of the single quotes around the 0, but that doesn't make any difference. Also, you shouldn't be relying on the default date format, but using `TO_DATE`.You don't say what DBMS you're using, but I tried both Oracle and MySQL.